# 'Missing data for not-null field' when attempting a join -- what could be causing this?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbt

We have two views that form part of a `dbt` pipeline.

The first looks something like this:

```
table_a (
  product_id   varchar,
  first_flag   boolean,
  second_flag  boolean
)
```

The second looks like this:

```
table_b (
  transport_id   varchar,
  product_id     varchar,
  some_timestamp timestamp
)
```

We're trying to do a simple (inner) join as follows:

```sql
with _products as (
    select distinct
        product_id
    from
        table_a
    where
        first_flag or
        second_flag
)
select
    transport_id,
    product_id,
    some_timestamp
from
    table_b
    inner join _products using (product_id)
```

But attempting to execute this query produces:

```
postgresql error: Missing data for not-null field DETAIL: 
error: Missing data for not-null field code:
```

For what it's worth, this can also be replicated by attempting other types of join (`left`, `right`, `full outer`...).

**What could be causing this error?** If I understand what's going on correctly, there's a column defined as non-null somewhere that the `dbt` pipeline that is attempting to populate with either a null or completely empty data.  However, I've checked both `table_a` and `table_b` for `NULL` in all the involved columns, and there are none.

Neither `table_a` nor `table_b` have been configured with any constraints as far as we can tell, which we have verified via the information schema.

How should I go about debugging this error?

Has anyone else observed similar behaviour before, and how did you resolve it?

## Update / Unsatisfying Workaround

We think this is probably a quirk with **dbt**. Without going into too much detail about the architecture of the data pipeline, "materializing" `table_a` as a physical table (rather than a view) seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Works well in PostgreSQL (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gixJYQR-)). Maybe Redshift has some quirk?

Comment: Just had this issue and while it is not exactly the same, this might help someone else! I had an issue when casting values, namely my issue was casting a space to float. `SELECT ' '::FLOAT` throws a nice error, but for my query it gave the above error I assume since my casting was deep into my query. Changing the cast to INT, gave me a better error: `ERROR:  Invalid digit, Value ' ', Pos 0, Type: Integer` and thus helped me find the error!!